# Cycle through only specific file types in PS using custom tab completion on the command line

Tags: powershell, tab-completion, programmable-completion

I use PowerShell's [PSReadline](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine)-based tab completion and I'm looking to implement the following custom completion behavior:

In a folder I have

```
File1.java
File1.class
File2.java
File2.class
```

If I use tab after `java` I got a list of the files:

```
java .\File
File1.java
File1.class
File2.java
File2.class
```

But I want to use a shortcut so I can scroll through only the .java-files but without the extension shown. I also want to get rid of ".\" in the name.

So if I write `java` and use tab I want to have

```
java File1
```

And next tab gives

```
java File2
```

And so forth (with tab or some other key).

I also wondering, before compling the java-files I have the folder

```
File1.java
File2.java
```

I now want to write javac and use tab so I get

```
javac File1.java
```

And tab again gives

```
javac File2.java
```

And so forth.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Register-ArgumentCompleter` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) (PSv5+):

```sh
# With `java`, cycle through *.java files, but without the extension.
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName java -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete)
    (Get-ChildItem $wordToComplete*.java).BaseName
}

# With `javac`, cycle through *.java files, but *with* the extension.
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName javac -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete)
    (Get-ChildItem $wordToComplete*.java).Name
}
```

---

To define an alternative key or chord for invoking completion, use [`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler); e.g., to make <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> invoke completions:

```sh
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+k -Function TabCompleteNext
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+shift+k -Function TabCompletePrevious
```

Note that this affects completion globally - you cannot implement a command-specific completion key that way.

Comment: Thanks, works great! Is it possible to change the shortcut for this? For instance ALT or CTRL, instead of TAB.

Comment: @JDoeDoe: Please see my update, but note that you won't be able to use a modifier key such as ALT or CTRL by itself - you must combine it with a non-modifier key.

Comment: I see! Also, CTRL+K affects all scripts using the function TabCompleteNext? I mean, can you somehow bind CTRL+K so it only invokes with javac and java?

Comment: @JDoeDoe: Yes, it affects completion globally; personally, I wouldn't go for a command-specific key - and I wouldn't know how to implement it off the top of my head. If it's important to you, I suggest you ask a new question.