# Custom tab completion in Git Bash / MinGW?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, mingw, git-bash

This [thread is for Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943911/cycle-through-only-specific-file-types-in-ps-using-custom-tab-completion-on-the). But I need help how to implement the same autocompletion behavior in Git Bash (MinGW) for Windows.

**Case 1:**

In a folder I have:

```
File1.java
File1.class
File2.java
File2.class
```

I want to use a shortcut so I can scroll through *only* the .java-files (and without the extension shown).

So if I write `java` and use tab I want to have

```
java File1
```

And next tab gives

```
java File2
```

**Case 2:**

Before compiling the java-files I have

```
File1.java
File2.java
```

I now want to write `javac` and use tab so I get

```
javac File1.java
```

And tab again gives

```
javac File2.java
```

And so forth.

Is this solvable?