# How to get the context directory in a CommandPredictor

Tags: c#, powershell, shell

I am playing with ICommandPredictor, a way to create [powershell predictor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.subsystem.icommandpredictor?view=powershellsdk-7.1.0) in C#

My goal is to show as suggestion the list of available git branch in the current directory, and by current directory I mean : "the location where is the shell calling the predictor"

But I cannot find a way to get it.

I tried Environment.CurrentDirectory, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() but it always return the starting location of the shell.
I also played a bit with [GetPSSubsystemCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.subsystem.getpssubsystemcommand?view=powershellsdk-7.1.0) and [SubsystemManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.subsystem.subsystemmanager?view=powershellsdk-7.1.0) but not luck for now.

I'm starting to think it is not possible to get this data.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/collecting-information-about-computers?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see at all how this can help me. Are you sure you pasted the good link ?

Comment: Yes.  The command predictor is under the Managing Computers. I used you link and went up a few levels and found my link.

Comment: Looking at the APIs I don't see a way to do this either, curiously. It's worth opening an issue at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: @jdweng, doubling down with a non sequitur after having been told that your comment is unhelpful is even more unhelpful.

Comment: Note that if you're looking for custom tab-completions _for a given command_, say `git`, using [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) is sufficient. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54945469/45375) for an example.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to choose in a menu style, using arrow key to select an option. 

Another idea if this isn't possible would be to create a console app with spectre...

Comment: @Ashijo, if you place `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Tab MenuComplete` in your `$PROFILE`, you'll get menu-style tab-completion.

Comment: @mklement0 It works :D just what I needed. Thank you.
I have still created a feature request for powershell because I think predictors are cool, and should be improved.